# scala: function which removes elements out of a list with a bigger predecessor

Tags: scala

I want to write a tail-recursive function in scala `biggerPredecessor` which removes elements out of a list which have a bigger predecessor.

for example:

```
(1,3,2,5,7)
```

should result in:

```
(1,3,5,7)
```

Here is what I have so far but now I got stuck.

```
def biggerPredecessor(xs: List[Int]) : List[Int] = (xs) match
  {
    def finalElements(ys: List[Int], xs: List[Int]) : List[Int] = (ys, xs) match
    {
      case (Nil, x::xs) => finalElements(new List(x), xs)
      case (y::ys, x::xs) if x > y => x::xs // insert in reverse order into list
      case (y::ys, Nil) => // ...
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does it need to be this complex?

Comment: I assume that for input `List(5,3,4,6)` the correct result should be `List(5,6)` and **not** `List(5,4,6)`.  Not all the answers provided so far produce this result.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
def biggerPredecessor(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    @tailrec
    def finalElements (xs: List[Int], acc: List[Int] ): List[Int] = xs match {
        case Nil => acc
        case head :: tail => finalElements(tail, if(acc.headOption.getOrElse(0) > head) acc else head :: acc)
    }

    finalElements(xs, List.empty[Int]).reverse
}
```

Or a bit more concise, using `foldLeft`:

```
foldLeft(List.empty[Int])((acc, elem) => if(acc.lastOption.getOrElse(0) > elem) acc else acc :+ elem))
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution would go with `foldLeft`:

```
  val seq = List(1,3,2,5,7)

  val result = seq.foldLeft(List[Int]()){
    case (Nil, x: Int) => List(x)
    case (ys, x) if x > ys.last => ys :+ x
    case (ys, x) => ys
  }

  println(result)
```

Here the version suggested by Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez:

```
 val result2 = seq.foldLeft(List.empty[Int]){
    case (Nil, x) => List(x)
    case (ys, x) if x > ys.head => x :: ys
    case (ys, x) => ys
  }.reverse
```

Ok, here the recursive translation suggested by jwvh:

```
  def biggerPredecessor(list: List[Int],
                        results: List[Int] = List.empty[Int]): List[Int] = (list, results) match {
    case (Nil, _) => results.reverse
    case (x::xs, Nil) => biggerPredecessor(xs, List(x))
    case (x::xs, y::_) if x > y => biggerPredecessor( xs,x :: results)
    case (_::xs, _) => biggerPredecessor(xs, results)
  }

  println(biggerPredecessor(seq))
```

This needs one more case, when the list is done.

You can paste this in [Scalafiddle](https://scalafiddle.io) and check yourself.

Comment: Nice solution, just a few things. First, it would be more optimal to just build the target list backwards _(using `::` and `head` instead of  `:+` and `last`)_ and then `reverse` it at the end. Second, you don't need to specify that `x` is an `Int` in your first case. Finally, I think is more readable and common to use `List.empty[Int]` than `List[Int]()` .

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez: thanks for your comment - I added your suggestion.

Comment: The only answer (so far) that handles input `List(-2,-4,-3,-1)` correctly. It is not, however, recursive as the OP requested.

Answer (score 1):

if you just need non-recursive solution then here it is:

```
def biggerPredecessor(ls: List[Int]) =
  ls.take(1) ++ ls
    .zip(ls.drop(1))
    .collect {
      case (l,r) if !(l>r) => r
    }
```

Comment: I love the approach. Just a hint, though: there's trouble in paradise when the sequence is empty.

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko Using `take(1)` and `drop(1)` might be cleaner than using `headOption` and `getOrElse`. `take` and `drop` are almost always a safer option than `head` and `tail`.

Comment: @Tim thanks. fixed the answer. it looks more elegant with take/drop. but probably a bit slower because of `++` instead of `::`

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko You could also use `collect` with a guard on the `case` to replace both the `filter` and `map`.

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of the `sliding` function:

```
def biggerPredecessor(xs: List[Int]) : List[Int] =
  (null.asInstanceOf[Int] :: xs) // null is the sentinel, because first item is always included
    .sliding(2)
    .flatMap {
      case List(a,b) => if (a > b) None else Some(b)
      case List(_) => None // special handling for empty xs
    }
    .toList


println(biggerPredecessor(List()))
println(biggerPredecessor(List(1)))
println(biggerPredecessor(List(1,2)))
println(biggerPredecessor(List(2,1)))
println(biggerPredecessor(List(1,3,2,5,7)))
```

[ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/oWaTU9M/0)

Comment: Wouldn't `Int.MinValue` make more sense as the sentinel?

Comment: Yes,  that would make more sense