# Scala: Iterating with access to multiple elements

Tags: scala, iterator

I have an iterator that contains all the data I need in some sort order. I would like to perform some operation on each data element that takes into account the preceding and subsequent element in the iterator. I.e. I have a function that, given n elements, takes arguments `f(iter(k-1), iter(k), iter(k+1))` for `0 < k < n-1`.

Of course, I cant just iterate over the iterator because I don't have access to the k + 1 element when I call the function.

I could just cast the whole thing do a list and use indexing, but that would be inelegant. What is the Scala way of accessing these values? Can I somehow compose the iterator with itself and an offset?

Comment: Scala collections have the `sliding` method. Iterators should have them too, but I am not sure on this one.

Comment: You can probably use the zipWithIndex method on list. However, creating the tuples is costly operation and you can use a view instead. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833653/7803797

Comment: You can try this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53378160/scala-function-which-removes-elements-out-of-a-list-with-a-bigger-predecessor/53378379#53378379

Comment: What is the expected behavior if the iterator has fewer than three elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider using method [sliding](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/Iterator.html#sliding[B%3E:A](size:Int,step:Int):Iterator.this.GroupedIterator[B]) for what you need.  Let's say function `f` returns the same type as the iterator's element type.  The following method `sliding3Iter` will supply a sliding window of 3 elements from a provided Iterator to function `f` as its arguments:

```
def sliding3Iter[T](it: Iterator[T], f: (T, T, T) => T): Iterator[T] =
  it.sliding(3).
    collect{ case ls if ls.size == 3 => f(ls(0), ls(1), ls(2)) }
```

For example:

```
val f = (i: Int, j: Int, k: Int) => i + j + k

val it = (0 to 10).toIterator

sliding3Iter(it, f).toList
// res1: List[Int] = List(3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27)
```

Comment: I feel,  like both answers could be combined to provide a better answer.  First,  collect is better than map,  because it covers iterators with less than 3 elements. Also,  collect can directly pattern match on seq of 3 elements,  like the other answer does.

Answer (score 3):

The comment from @ygor is correct.

```
yourIterator.sliding(3)
            .collect{ case Seq(prev, current, next) =>
              //proceed accordingly
            }
```

Note that the code doesn't know which is the final collection-of-3. The last element in `yourIterator` will never be `current`.

Comment: This will fail,  if number of elements in iterator is less than 3. I burned myself on this one few times.